# How to group multiple columns data

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the below table I want to group the product name then sum the quantity to be under each Model name.

### tblStore

| ID | Product | Model | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Banana | M1 | 1.00 |
| 2 | Apple | M3 | 0.50 |
| 3 | Pawpaw | M3 | 1.50 |
| 4 | Orange | M2 | 2.00 |
| 5 | Banana | M1 | 1.00 |
| 6 | Orange | M1 | 0.50 |

```
Select Product, 
    Sum(Case When tblStore.Quantity  = 'M1' Then 1 Else 0 End) As M1,
    Sum(Case When tblStore.Quantity  = 'M2' Then 1 Else 0 End) As M2,
    Sum(Case When tblStore.Quantity  = 'M3' Then 1 Else 0 End) As M3
From tblStore
Group by Name
```

Expected output

| Product | M1 | M2 | M3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Banana | 2.0 |  |  |
| Apple |  |  | 0.5 |
| Pawpaw |  |  | 1.5 |
| Orange | 0.5 | 2.0 |  |

Comment: `Sum(CASE WHEN tblStore.Quantity = 'M<n>' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END) as M<n>`

Comment: also, it should be group by product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your column references a bit backwards, you are after the following:

```
select Product, 
 Sum(case when Model = 'M1' then Qty else 0 end) M1,
 Sum(case when Model = 'M2' then Qty else 0 end) M2,
 Sum(case when Model = 'M3' then Qty else 0 end) M3
from tblStore 
group by Product;
```